# Почему Android Studio не видит apply?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Пытаюсь перейти на Kotlin, но при попытке использовать apply, IDE кричит что такого метода нет. Как исправить?

```
class TableStage : Stage() {

init {

    val stageLayout = Table()
    addActor(stageLayout.apply {
        debugAll()
        setFillParent(true)
    ...
```

> Unresolved reference: apply

Answer (score 1):

поставил Android Studio Preview v.3.0 и все заработало